# How to feed an image sequence into a CNN while keeping input images independent?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm using a convolutional neural network (CNN) to preprocess my input for a Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM). I have the following input dimensions: 128 x 10 x 3 x 32 x 32 (batch size, sequence length, color channel, height, width) and would like to obtain the following output dimensions: 128 x 10 x 480 (batch size, sequence length, output CNN/ input LSTM size). Is the code below maintaining the sequence dimension correctly? Am I processing multiple images independently here or are the dimensions getting mixed up? Inputs and Outputs are shaped as they should be, but I'm uncertain about the intermedia steps.

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN_coords, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 10, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, 5)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(20, 30, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)

    def forward(self, i):
        x = i.reshape(-1, i.shape[2], i.shape[3], i.shape[4])
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
        x = x.view(i.shape[0], i.shape[1], -1)
        return x
```

The goal is to leave the time dimension for the LSTM. The architecture looks like this:
[image: architecture]